# Inheritance with multiple xcdatamodel

Tags: ios, core-data

Hi I'm creating a private pod that uses core data.

This pod contains a .xcdatamodel file.

The project that uses the pod has also another xcdatamodel. How can I relate both xcdatamodel? How can I link classes between them?

Basically I want to create two layers: The pod xcdatamodel that is always stable and it doesn't change and the xcdatamodel in the project that changes and uses classes described in the pod xcdatamodel.

Any ideas how can I do this? Maybe core data is not the technology for this and I have to use another framework?

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like you would want to merge the data models when the app starts up. If you create one `NSManagedObjectModel` for the pod's model and one for the app's model, you would merge them using `NSManagedObjectModel(byMerging:)` to combine them. Then go ahead and add the persistent store, etc, and you're done.

Comment: Wow exciting, I will investigate. Thanks!